# Why doesn't UIViewController fill the window when rotating, while UINavigationController does?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, autorotate

I've just noticed that when a UIViewController is the root controller on a window, autorotation bleeds a bit of the window through as it's rotating.

[image: UIViewController as root controller]

This is not the case when you use a UINavigationController as the root controller, however. What is UINavigationController doing differently to avoid the bleed-through?

[image: UINavigationController as root controller]

Comment: The Navigation Controller must have the jaggies property set to NO ;)

Comment: `[self setViewCanHasJaggies: NO];`, seriously though, are they both set to Opaque?

Comment: No modifications; these are just stock controllers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess (unfortunately I don't have a good Xcode presently to test), is that it's related to UIViewController's `wantsFullScreenLayout` property. I suspect that UINavigationController returns `YES`, and default VCs return `NO`.

Comment: Interesting. This does fix the issue! It must have to do with the view's frame not being the same size as the window, causing the frames to animate slightly differently.